# differences in days lack of 1 days (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, date-fns

I'm using date-fns to calcualte day differences

```
import differenceInDays from "date-fns/differenceInDays";

console.log(
  differenceInDays(
    new Date("2020-08-12T07:22:03.498Z"),
    new Date("2020-08-09T09:30:20.914Z")
  )
);
```

The answer is 2, I'm expecting 3, since 12-9 is 3.

What's wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-v2-pzlex?file=/src/index.js:0-299

Comment: It's not whole `3` days. It's `2 days and 21 hours`. Therefore date-fns returns `2`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz how to ignore the time? I just want the day difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Difference in whole days

The reason for getting full days only is that that is how that API works as per the official docs for [DifferenceInDays](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/differenceInDays)

#### Difference in calendar days

What you're looking for is the difference in calendar days, which is natively supported by `date-fns` as can be seen in the documentation for [differenceInCalendarDays](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/differenceInCalendarDays).

Underwater this API just strips the time, which seems to be what you are looking for.

#### Example

```js
import differenceInCalendarDays from "date-fns/differenceInCalendarDays";

console.log(
  differenceInCalendarDays(
    new Date("2020-08-12T07:22:03.498Z"),
    new Date("2020-08-09T09:30:20.914Z")
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the date, remove the time until the timezone

```
console.log(
  differenceInDays(
    new Date("2020-08-12"),
    new Date("2020-08-09")
  )
);

// returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It should show  the number of **full days** between the given dates. (You lack a few hours for 3 complete days)

So, if you change the final date time to `new Date("2020-08-12T09:30:20.914Z")`

It will show 3 days.